# To instantiate BiMap Of google-collections in Java

Tags: java, guava, bimap

**How can you instantiate a `Bimap` of Google-collections?**

I've read the question [Java: Instantiate Google Collection's HashBiMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533513/java-instantiate-google-collections-hashbimap)

**A sample of my code**

```
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;

public class UserSettings {

 private Map<String, Integer> wordToWordID;

 UserSettings() {

  this.wordToWordID = new BiMap<String. Integer>();
```

I get `cannot instantiate the type BiMap<String, Integer>`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As stated in the linked question, you are supposed to use the `create()` factory methods.

In your case, this means changing

```
this.wordToWordID = new BiMap<String. Integer>();
```

to

```
this.wordToWordID = HashBiMap.create();
```

Comment: Hmm. Your answer raises a new question. **Why does EnumBimap not have the method `create` without parameters, like HashBiMap?**

Comment: @Masi: That's a good question. I believe the reason is because EnumBimap needs to know what its parameters are, and because of type erasure it can't know unless you pass the `Class` objects to it at some point. The same is true of `EnumMap` and `EnumSet` in the standard library.

Comment: So it is not enough for `EnumMap` to know the types only. It apparently makes some processing based on the content of the input data.

Comment: @Masi: Yes, if you look at the source you can see that `EnumMap` uses the `Class` object to figure out what all the possible values of the enum are (and for other things; you can see the OpenJDK source at https://openjdk.dev.java.net/source/browse/openjdk/jdk/trunk/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/EnumMap.java?rev=257&view=markup). `EnumBimap` requires the `Class` arguments simply because it uses two `EnumMap` instances (see the source here: http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/EnumBiMap.java).

Answer (score 6):

[BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) is an interface, and as such cannot be instantiated. You need to instantiate a concrete subclass according to the properties you want, available subclasses (according to the javadoc) are [EnumBiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EnumBiMap.html), [EnumHashBiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EnumHashBiMap.html), [HashBiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html), [ImmutableBiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableBiMap.html).

Comment: URL's no more up to date

Answer (score 6):

Another cool way to create a BiMap, but in this case an immutable BiMap, is using the `ImmutableBiMap.Builder`.

```
static final ImmutableBiMap<String, Integer> WORD_TO_INT =
   new ImmutableBiMap.Builder<String, Integer>()
       .put("one", 1)
       .put("two", 2)
       .put("three", 3)
       .build();
```

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableBiMap.html

Comment: I think this is even better than Michael's answer in some cases. Immutable for efficiency, not having nulls.  What do you think? I think this feature appeared after I asked the question. Manual about it here http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableBiMap.html

Comment: Props for the javadocs @Masi, it didn't occur to me to put them here as well. I guess that Immutability vs. Mutability is a different discussion, but as I always use immutable objects I just thought that at least this way was worth a mention.